# cURL save file and rename?

Tags: php, curl

I'm downloading and saving a file from another server to my server, except the file I'm downloading comes attached with an access token.

```
http://www.example.com/video.mp4?versionId=c_.Qeh.dz.zqPA3zc57HFDKEAmKG3xr2
```

Loading the following results in a permission error:

```
http://www.example.com/video.mp4
```

Problem is, when I cURL with the following code:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/video.mp4?versionId=c_.Qeh.dz.zqPA3zc57HFDKEAmKG3xr2';
$fh = fopen(basename($url), "wb");
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The file saves as video.mp4?versionId=c_.Qeh.dz.zqPA3zc57HFDKEAmKG3xr2 (with token) and not video.mp4, which means I can't do anything with it afterwards as it's not an .mp4

What's the solution here? I tried

```
rename(video.mp4?versionId=c_.Qeh.dz.zqPA3zc57HFDKEAmKG3xr2, video.mp4)
```

but it requires filenames and the access token is preventing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `parse_url` instead of `basename` or combine them. Take path from `parse_url` (without GET params) and then use `basename` function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Thanks, I'm worried if I parse the query from the url, I won't be able to cURL the file as I will lose the access token. I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

try `basename( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_PATH ) )`